# How to make a UIView autosize to full screen when switching orientation

Tags: ipad, ios, uiview

Do I need to write code to make a UIView fill up the window area when switching orientation? Is there a simple setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the view initially takes up the whole screen, and the app is set to autorotate, all you should have to do is set the autoresizing mask on the view to resize width and height:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Edit: see my comment below for how to do this in IB

Comment: Yes, in IB, select your view, bring up the inspector, go to the 3rd tab (looks like a ruler) there you will see a section titled "autosizing", you can change the autoresizing mask there by clicking on the red marks.  Kinda hard to explain, but it makes sense when you find it.  [Here is an image of what you want it to look like](http://i.imgur.com/eP9Hc.png)